# conversion decimal to 2^12 binary form

Tags: java

anyone can help me how to convert a decimal number into 2^12 binary form...here the code that i used for conversion. bt it's not 2^12 binary for. pls do anyone help me to solve this prob.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class convert {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bf= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter any number:");
    String sn = bf.readLine();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(sn);
    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    System.out.println("Binary number is:" + s);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get and what were you expecting? if you enter 4096 (which is 2^12) you should see 1000000000000.

Comment: you going to answer @Peter's question?  Or is this just not that important to you?

Comment: @Peter (from OP who created a new account and couldn't comment on his own question) helo mr.peter, lets say if i enter 201 and the output is 1100110. it's in 7 digit binary form. bt i want the ans in 12 digit example 201 in binary is 000001100110.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the OP wants a binary string padded to 12 digits.  There are many ways to do this, here is one:

```
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(i);

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = 1; j <= 12 - s.length(); j++) {
 buf.append('0');
}
buf.append(s);
s = buf.toString();

System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be shorter with formatter. Something like,

```
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
System.out.println(String.format("%012d", Integer.valueOf(s)));
```

Comment: This method fails with an input string of "4095".  You have to be careful parsing a binary string back into an Integer object, as the binary string is significantly longer than a decimal string would be.

Comment: RD you are right. It should be better with a System.out.println( String.format("%012d",Long.valueOf(a)) ); or BigInteger.